# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, streamlit

I have built a streamlit app and wanted to host in heroku. But when I host it, it is throwing me the following error.

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I saw all the previous forums, the suggestion is to

```
apt get libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libice6
```

But since I am using heroku git as a mode to push, I am not using heroku CLI, how can I solve this problem ?
I have added Aptfile in my project folder. But how do I make it run while deploying the app in heroku?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Followed many blogs.
The answer that I found is in the blog below:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-your-opencv-flask-web-application-on-heroku-c23efcceb1e8